Tkinter GUI tittle change
I'm working on a semaphore synchronization project, and I’m trying to run a barrier script (barrier.py) using the command:
python Sync.py sync_code/barrier.py

# simple barrier

## initalization
count = 0
mutex = Semaphore(1)
barrier = Semaphore(0)


## Thread code
# rendezvous

mutex.wait()
    count = count + 1
    if count == num_threads(): barrier.signal()
mutex.signal()

barrier.wait()
barrier.signal()

# critical point

By default, the Tkinter window title shows up as "tk". I want to change this window title to "Barrier".
I tried adding this code at the beginning of barrier.py to set the title
import tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Barrier") 

However, this results in two windows opening: A blank window titled "Barrier" + The actual simulation window with the "tk" title that runs my barrier synchronization code
I want to change the title of the main simulation window (where barrier.py is running) to "Barrier" without opening an extra window.
How can I set the title of the existing main window created by Sync.py to "Barrier" without creating an extra window? Is there a way to access or modify the title of the main Tkinter window directly in Sync.py?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

You need to post the code of sync.py.  Also there is indentation issue in your first code block.

Just call the title() method of whatever object is running the main window in sync.py, the same way you are doing up there. You can call that method whenever you want, without needing to use the config() method.

I thought that I need to modify my barrier file instead. but yes it works now!
